# How to get all post labels containing numbers only?

Tags: blogger

I have a bloggger post in the following labels : Shoes, Men, 20%, **89**
I just want to get a label that contains a number,In my case I want to get **89** label
I tried a lot of ways like :

```
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'> <b:if cond='data:label.name gte 10'><data:label.name/> </b:if> </b:loop>
```

and

```
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'> <b:if cond='data:label.name > &quot;0&quot;   &quot;1&quot; or data:label.name  contains &quot;2&quot; or data:label.name  contains &quot;3&quot; or data:label.name  contains &quot;4&quot; or data:label.name  contains &quot;5&quot; or data:label.name  contains &quot;6&quot; or data:label.name  contains &quot;7&quot; or data:label.name  contains &quot;8&quot; or data:label.name  contains &quot;9&quot; or data:label.name  contains &quot;0&quot; '><data:label.name/> </b:if> </b:loop>
```

But it did not give the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Label name treats as a string (data type) not a number so you can't perform a comparison using some number operators like `gte` `lte`. You can use string operators `==` `!=` `contains`

**Also**, in the conditional tag, you have to enclose the string with double quotes `"89"` or `&quot;89&quot;`

```
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
    <b:if cond='data:label.name == "20%"'>
        <data:label.name/> 
    </b:if>
</b:loop>
```

**Edit**: If you want get post labels containing any number

```
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
    <b:if cond='data:label.name contains "0" or data:label.name contains "1" or data:label.name contains "2" or data:label.name contains "3" or data:label.name contains "4" or data:label.name contains "5" or data:label.name contains "6" or data:label.name contains "7" or data:label.name contains "8" or data:label.name contains "9"'>
        <data:label.name/>
    </b:if>
</b:loop>
```

Comment: But I want to get only  "89" label, and exclude other labels.

Comment: So, use this `<b:if cond='data:label.name == "89"'>
        <data:label.name/> 
    </b:if>`

Comment: You didn't understand me, I mean the labels contain only numbers.

Comment: `<b:if cond='data:label.name contains "89"'> <data:label.name/> </b:if>`

Comment: Please try to re-read my question, I gave you an example of a number, I want to get the label that has only a number, not necessarily the number 89

Answer (score 0):

As in @Bassam's answer:

> Label name treats as a string (data type) not a number so you can't perform a comparison using some number operators like gte lte. You can use string operators `==`, `!=`, `contains`.

**But**, you can create another loop inside for a range of numbers and check if label name matches one of numbers within this range, like that:

```xml
<b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
  <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
    <b:loop values='1 to 100' var='num'>
      <b:if cond='data:label.name == data:num'><data:label.name/></b:if>
    </b:loop>
  </b:loop>
</b:if>
```

Consider increase the end of range if you have labels with name more than 100.

Comment: Hello, He wants to detect numbers inside label name not label index

Comment: Hello @Bassam , this loop not for index, it compares label name to each result of loop, so if label name is "89" or whatever number within 1 to 100 range, condition will return `true`, just try it.

Comment: Ok, It's a good answer but the label name may contain letters and symbols like 20% beside the limitation of the loop range from 1 to 100 and I think there is  performance costs when looping through this range compared by my answer which tests 10 cases or fewer.

Comment: Sure you're right about performance costs so he should decrease the odds range as minimum as he can, but in your answer `contains "num"` expression will not work with `label.name` and return *invalid expression* error, did you test it?

Comment: Tested, It's working, I usually test my Blogger code to avoid such errors.

Comment: Maybe I tested it in a wrong way it not works for me, I'll keep my answer until @jimi-del confirms the right one. I really appreciate your interest to improve Blogger developers community and I looking forward to contact with you if you would like. 

Comment: Thank you, I have the honer and great pleasure to contact with you. This is [my fb](https://www.facebook.com/Basssamy)